# Python3 error “ImportError: No module named” have __init__.py

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, importerror, directory-structure

I created a simple flask application and my directory structure looks like this:

```
myproject
- src
-- models
--- __init__.py
-- views
--- errors.py
--- default.py
-- application.py
-- config.py
-- __init__.py
- test
-- test_myproject.py
Readme.md
setup.py
..
```

The **application.py** from the src look like this:

```
from src.models import db
from src.views.errors import error_pages
from src.views.scoreboard import scoreboard
from src.config import config
```

The **test_myproject** looks like this:

```
from src.models import db, Result
from src.application import create_app
```

I use Pycharm to develop this and when I click run it works but when I try to run it via the command line `python application.py` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/application.py", line 18, in <module>
    from src.models import db
ImportError: No module named 'src'
```

Runnint the unittests with `python -m unittest` works.

If I change the imports from **application.py** to:

```
from models import db
from views.errors import error_pages
from views.scoreboard import scoreboard
from config import config
```

It will work when I run it via the command line, however the tests won't work anymore.

```
File ".../src/application.py", line 18, in <module>
    from models import db
ImportError: No module named 'models'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check value of PYTHONPATH environment variable in both cases

Comment: in `__init__` try adding `from .models import *`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said that you're running `python application.py`, which suggests that your working directory is `src`. To be able to import modules under `src.*` (without playing with PYTHONPATH) you should run Python from the `myproject` directory instead.

Consider either moving `application.py` to `myproject` or running it with `python src/application.py`.

Comment: Thank you! This is good to know, in the end, I chose the PYTHON PATH